# Excel: How to do conditional formatting based on two cell values?

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

This particular question is regarding highlighting dates on a pre-made calendar.

Please see screenshot below:
[image]

I need to highlight the cell in the calendar that matches both the task and the date in the data table. For example- see L3 and P4. In the screenshot they are highlighted manually for demonstration.

Can someone please help me out with this. I've been using AND, but screwing up somewhere with the $.

Comment: can you post a link to a file? or show examples of your code/function? Also.. a bit more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't entering any data and using this as a visual tool you can spoof the spreadsheet by placing a period into the cell that matches the values you need, and then conditional format based on `specific text` and enter the period as the text.

This image demonstrates it as two separate tables; One with only the formula used to look for the values, and the second one formatting the background and font to be the same color (effectively hiding the period)

It its definitely a workaround and will only work if this is a visual tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Data Table goes down to row 7, try entering this Conditional Formatting formula with cell B3 selected:

```
=COUNTIFS($AI$4:$AI$7,$B3,$AJ$4:$AJ$7,C$2)>0
```

Comment: And then copy B3 to all the other cells in the calendar.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, I was assuming that the area was selected and cell B3 activated when the conditional formatting is entered, although I guess I didn't quite say that.